# Run Neo4J locally on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I am trying to get this [neo4j project (sdn)](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn) to run locally on ubuntu. Based on the [instructions](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn#deploying-locally). I have done the following:

1. Installed neoj4 on ubuntu using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-neo4j-on-an-ubuntu-vps)
2. Set user and pass to **neo4j/neopass** in the web-ui: http://localhost:7474/browser/
3. Added `export GRAPHENEDB_URL="http://neo4j:neopass@localhost:7474"` to my **~/.bashrc** file.
4. Executed:  `neo4j-shell -c < categorySetup.cql`
5. Started the web app with: `mvn clean spring-boot:run`

But when I access it at http://localhost:8080/ I just get empty drop down menus. This is the output in the terminal:

```
2016-07-16 18:10:06,611 ERROR 4j.ogm.session.response.RowModelResponse:  47 - failed to parse: {"row":[[{"name":"Bacon"},{},{"categoryColor":"#FF0000","name":"Meat"}]],"meta":[[{"id":8,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":0,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":1,"type":"node","deleted":false}]]}
2016-07-16 18:10:06,627  WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: 542 - 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "meta" (class org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.RowModelResult), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "row"])
 at [Source: {"row":[[{"name":"Bacon"},{},{"categoryColor":"#FF0000","name":"Meat"}]],"meta":[[{"id":8,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":0,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":1,"type":"node","deleted":false}]]}; line: 1, column: 82] (through reference chain: org.neo4j.ogm.session.result.RowModelResult["meta"])
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) ~[javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:na]
```

Based on below I tried to build + run tests (**mvn clean install**) on [sdn-4.1](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn-4.1) but it fails because of missing dependencies:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flavorwocky: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.flavorwocky:flavorwocky:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.0.M1, org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:4.1.0.M1, org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:tests:4.1.0.M1: Failure to find org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.0.M1 in
```

I tried to use latest released versions of those, but then I got a bunch of class not found errors when the tests where run:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/ogm/service/ResourceService
```

Seems [sdn-4.1](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn-4.1) is broken compared to [sdn](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn) which builds fine +all tests run so for now I will try to get the project to run on [sdn](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn)

Comment: Where are you running Neo4j? The project you're working with assumes Neo4j is running with a 3rd-party hoster.

Comment: @DavidMakogon this is just a variable pointing to neo4j, the project works very well with a local instance.

Comment: @u123 How did you executed the cypher script ? Also, neo4j prompts you to change the password when you launch the neo4j browser for the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a local neo4j, specify the password you used when launching neo4j for the first time or disable auth for playing.

You best use the `sdn-4.1` branch, actually the `sdn` branch has some issues and is not maintained since a year.

Secondly, there is no `/categories` endpoint, the right endpoint is `/api/categories` which is used by the angular app and return some json, after running the `cql` script I have the following response :

```
[{"@id":"1","name":"Eggs and Dairy","categoryColor":"#D6C2AD","id":7864},{"@id":"2","name":"Meat","categoryColor":"#FF0000","id":7865},{"@id":"3","name":"Vegetable","categoryColor":"#009933","id":7866},{"@id":"4","name":"Seafood","categoryColor":"#0000CC","id":7867},{"@id":"5","name":"Fruit","categoryColor":"#FF9900","id":7868},{"@id":"6","name":"Nuts and Grains","categoryColor":"#993333","id":7869},{"@id":"7","name":"Herbs and Spices","categoryColor":"#FFF2BA","id":7870},{"@id":"8","name":"Condiments","categoryColor":"#CC66FF","id":7871}]
```